# Password sent via HTTPS accessible via browser developer tools

Tags: security

I have a web site that accomplishes user login via ajax call over https. Obviously the request contains the password. Playing around with Firefox developer tools I noticed that I can inspect any network requests coming from my page including the request body ... and there is my password. I assume the request is being encrypted since its over https but the developer tools still shows it as plain text. Am I missing something? If a user logs in on a public machine and forgets to logout anyone can use developer tools to grab their password. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

-Mike

Comment: you might look at implementing something like HMAC authentication, in which you send only a hash of the password. also, browsers typically don't store TLS/SSL requests in cache. Of course, without 2-factor authentication, a public machine might just as easily have a keylogger running, or so forth; there are myriad ways in which password authentication could be defeated by a compromised machine in the middle; HMAC +:2-factor auth via e.g. SMS is currently one of the better ways to guard against them.

Comment: @BRPocock: Browsers not storing SSL pages in cache is an old myth.  They absolutely do store SSL pages in cache just like regular unsecured HTTP pages, following any directives in the `Cache-Control` header.

Comment: wow, did not realise this has been the default setting for a while now. Confirmed it's off on my Firefox, but a little surprised. Thanks josh###

Comment: Storing pages and storing POST data is different. HMAC authentication doesn't imply any kind of encryption. Besides the social aspect, sending just a password hash is no better than sending the actual password.

Answer (score 10):

Everything is functioning by design – there's nothing wrong.

The browser's dev tools are intended to allow the user to inspect everything that's happening in the page – without that functionality, they'd be pretty useless.  The dev tools' network tab shows HTTP data *before* it is encrypted.

In the public machine scenario, remember that the dev tools only show network requests that happened after the tools were opened, so an attacker can't just open the dev tools after the user leaves with your page up and see the plaintext auth request.

Comment: Hi @josh3736 , Is it documented somewhere ?
I need to give a proof ?

Comment: The [official docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/) don't really have anything explicit to say other than "requests are only logged while the DevTools are open".

Comment: But what if any memory reading tool is installed in the system.. it can fetch the information stored over the network right ?
Is that a possibility ?

Comment: If there's malware reading your system memory, you have much larger problems, and they have nothing to do with the Dev Tools.

Answer (score 5):

> I can inspect any network requests coming from my page including the request body

No you can't - that's not yet network traffic - that's a HTTP datagram which is then passed through the SSL layer before it gets to the TCP stack.

> If a user logs in on a public machine and forgets to logout anyone can use developer tools to grab their password

No, because unless the page developer is doing really stupid things, the browser does not *store* the information - you could only see it because your browser was configured to intercept the information and store it temporarily. But having said that there are a large number of things which can cause the browser to store authentication tokens - auto complete and password managers for a start (the latter vary greatly in the quality of their implementation, the former has little protection against disclosure). Authentication tokens should never be sent as GET parameters hence should not be visilible from the browser history.