# Chrome dev tools shows Facebook password in plaintext even over HTTPS

Tags: security, http, authentication, web, https

I was playing around with the chrome dev tools when I noticed that whenever I logged on to Facebook over HTTP, the network tab in the dev tool could show me the body of that request and the username and password present in the packet body.

I then switched to HTTPS (even ticked the setting in the setting page to always use HTTPS). Even then, my password was still appearing in plain text. Why is that? Below are screenshots proving that. (Note I input the wrong password for security reasons)

[image: password and email in plaintext even though over HTTPS]

Is it just encrypted after the network tool sniffs that packet? How can I test to make sure that packet really is encrypted?

For reference, is a dump of the POST request:

```
Request URL:https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headers
:host:www.facebook.com
:method:POST
:path:/login.php?login_attempt=1
:scheme:https
:version:HTTP/1.1
accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
accept-encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
accept-language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,pt;q=0.4
cache-control:max-age=0
content-length:324
content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
// Deleted a few cookies for security reasons...
dnt:1
origin:https://www.facebook.com
referer:https://www.facebook.com/?stype=lo&jlou=Afd7GLl1MQLgCyvMMjJenU4EvxR4ANAAflf50TeVZaJHh-yNP6tZEzME3PYy-DNM3CVM8ttZVaZGimz6ijlniIJDFRiB-0Qw-DC7nSw4tHLIiw&smuh=30769&lh=Ac8k0ZF0uJVvz4_n
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117 Safari/537.36
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
login_attempt:1
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
lsd:AVqqq2cf
email:gkrinker@gmail.com
pass:123
persistent:1
default_persistent:1
timezone:-60
//deleted a few session ids for security reasons...
locale:en_Uiew source
cache-control:private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
content-encoding:gzip
content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8
date:Tue, 25 Feb 2014 22:12:02 GMT
expires:Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
p3p:CP="Facebook does not have a P3P policy. Learn why here: http://fb.me/p3p"
pragma:no-cache
set-cookie:wd=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.facebook.com; httponly
set-cookie:act=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.facebook.com; httponly
set-cookie:datr=TuvNUR6ZSfKVMK3QwA50-qF8; expires=Thu, 25-Feb-2016 22:12:02 GMT; path=/; domain=.facebook.com; httponly
set-cookie:sfiu=AYi8HE2Cetp79id0RVGdEL2fpeUeVwYCuNpgooZtuzNhmseXX4IOJza76oWsoRIhFgvt2CzXEC5AR6j5J2nhUHrrSxrkcXJp3J2QXFMWGn7tCYbZWATyigAk8GXLm-1VkVttzp2hgVEXKNS7e5Tdxw0gOhcX-1yK8jp6sgEwPPRXcQ; path=/; domain=.facebook.com; httponly
set-cookie:dpr=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.facebook.com; httponly
set-cookie:_e_0BOa_1=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.facebook.com; httponly
set-cookie:reg_ext_ref=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.facebook.com
set-cookie:reg_fb_ref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Flogin.php%3Flogin_attempt%3D1; path=/; domain=.facebook.com
set-cookie:_e_0BOa_0=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.facebook.com; httponly
status:200
strict-transport-security:max-age=0
version:HTTP/1.1
x-content-type-options:nosniff
x-fb-debug:gAsXRZwDHjUchVaRN+tSxFB1HNch3rTCqXW6744DdQI=
x-frame-options:DENY
x-xss-protection:0
```

Comment: Someone should correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm pretty sure since Chrome generated the request it just caches the form values locally. It's not actually being sent over plain text. If you want to verify this, spin up Wireshark and intercept the request. It should be encrypted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Password sent via HTTPS accessible via browser developer tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21514890/password-sent-via-https-accessible-via-browser-developer-tools) and [Should data in an HTTPS request appear as encrypted in Chrome developer tools?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306839/should-data-in-an-https-request-appear-as-encrypted-in-chrome-developer-tools)